# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SMTP'

Tags: python, error-handling, raspberry-pi, smtp, system

[image: error]

[image: error2]

I don't know why this is happening. Can someone please help?

Comment: Add a reproducible code snippet to your question so others can run and test your code. Images are not useful.

Comment: _Pictures_ of _text_?  Why not simply post the text?  Deadlines are your problem, and demands for a quick answer never appreciated - no one deliberately withholds and answer if they have one.  I removed that part of your question.  The speed of obtaining an answer is closely correlated with the quality of the question.

Comment: The error message states exactly what the problem is.  What more could anyone add.  Lookinga the smtplib [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html), it clearly has no member `SMTP`.  It has `SMTP_SSL` and `LMTP`.  The example in the documentation however does use `SMTP` - but that's Python for you - a pile of poorly designed badly documented dung.  Note also that coding on an RPi does not on its own  make this worthy of the `embedded` tag - removed, `python` added.